# Batch Script command at prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, input

This may seem like a stupid question but I have this Simple Script:

```
@ECHO OFF 
XCOPY c:\test c:\backupfolder /m /e
```

Because there is no folder backupfolder it prompts you if it is a folder or file how using the script to automatically put in The Letter "D" for directory in the prompt

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When copying to a folder, which is the usual case, add a backslash to the end of the path.
Adding quotes protects the command from spaces etc in the paths.

```
@ECHO OFF 
XCOPY "c:\test\*.*" "c:\backupfolder\" /m /e
```

Answer (score 0):

The `/i` switch causes `xcopy` to assume the destination is a directory as long as there is more than one file to copy.

But to make it work even if copying just one file, you could simply create the directory first:

```
@echo off
mkdir c:\backupfolder 2>NULL
xcopy /me c:\test c:\backupfolder
```

The `2>NULL` (redirecting standard error to `NULL`) suppresses the error message that occurs if the directory already exists.

Comment: You can also use `if not exist c:\backupfolder mkdir c:\backupfolder` instead of redirecting the error `2>NULL`

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I'll leave my answer as is so both options are represented. Presumably the `mkdir` call does essentially the same thing, but your version may be more efficient.